# Django “TypeError: list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id''” error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect to a page I intend to implement as an object's homepage after creation of one.
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from f.models import Post


def list(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'post': post,
    }
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)


def detail(request, id=None):
    Post = get_object_or_404(post, id=id)
    context = {
        'Post': Post,
    }
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.list, name='list'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]{1,3})$', views.list, name='detail'),
]
```

and my error

```
Django Version:     1.9.10
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Python Version:     3.5.2
```

Comment: a full stacktrace goes a long way in solving problems

Comment: In your urlpatterns the second item should contain views.detail, not views.list

Answer (score 2):

Look at the route:

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]{1,3})$', views.list, name='detail'),
```

You are sending the detail url to the list view `views.list` instead of the detail view `views.detail`.

As an aside, it would be better to pick a different name for you list view since `list` shadows the built-in name [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: thank u 
and i have new problem
NameError: name 'post' is not defined
views.py
def detail(request, id=None):
    posts1 = get_object_or_404(post, id=id)
    context = {
        'posts1': posts1,
    }
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)

def list(request):
    post = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'post': post,
    }
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)

Comment: it should be `post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)`, not `Post = get_object_or_404(post, id=id)`

Comment: tnx but not show anything detail in page
`def detail(request, id=None):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    context = {
        'post': post,
    }
    return render(request, 'detail.html', context)
`